# How to hide horizontal line in extjs

Tags: extjs

```
this.horizontalLine = {
    xtype: 'box',
    hidden: false,
    autoEl : {
        tag : 'hr'
    }
};
```

I want to hide this horizontal line. But

```
this.horizontalLine.hide()
```

is undefined.
I tried using `this.horizontalLine.hidden = true` also. In that case, hidden property is set as true but the line is still visible. Is there some other way to do this?

Comment: i think `.hide()` would be more appropriate in this case :). Besides that if your getting show is undefined then the component probably hasn't been initialized. You would be better of using Ext.create to create the component. what is the scope of `this` in your example above?

Comment: The component is initialised and it has scope where i use [.show()] .But I get "undefined is not a function" error .

Comment: If .hide() or .show() are undefined then it's not initialised, try console.log(this); above your hide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I resolved the issue by placing the horizontal line in a panel and hiding the panel insted.

```
    this.rulesLabel = new Ext.form.Label({
    text : 'Rules:',
    style : 'font-size:11px;font-weight:bold;color:#15428B;padding-right:10px;padding-top:50px; margin-left:10px;'
});

this.horizontalLine = {
    xtype: 'box',
    autoEl : {
        tag : 'hr'
    }
};

this.lineHolder = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'lineHolder',
    hidden : true,
    border: false,
    layout : 'form',
    bodyStyle : 'padding-top:10px;',
    items : [{xtype: 'box'},this.rulesLabel, this.horizontalLine]
});
```

I used `this.lineHolder.show()` and `this.lineHolder.hide()` to show and hide the line respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this.horizontalLine.hidden = true;

Comment: There is no error when i use this.horizontalLine.hidden = true; and the hidden property is set as true but the line is still visible. Same is the issue when i define horizontal line  as 'this.horizontalLine = {
    xtype: 'box',
    hidden: false,
    autoEl : {
        tag : 'hr'
    }
};' and use this.horizontalLine.hidden = false;  ie. the line will still be hidden eventhough the hidden property is set as false

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.Component` has a [`hide()`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-hide) method, so your code should work.

See a working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/ku7